# .NET Class with array -> How can i get the Values in my Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i make a .NET-Class with an array with some strings in a seperate project.

Now i have a second project with a Form and a combobox. I need the values from the array in my combobox to select it. The class is added in my project. I think I need to add the array from the class in a second array in my form first. How can i get this?

I search many things but I don't understand the problem why it doesn't work. Thank you very much and I hope you can help me to understand the problem.

Class:

```
public class ListMachinetyp 
    {
        public string[] machinetype = new string[] {
            "Machine 1",
            "Machine 2",
            "Machine 3"
            };
```

Form:

```
public Form1()
{
  string[] machinetyp = new string[] { };
  InitializeComponent();
  cbox.Items.Add(machinetyp);
}
```

Comment: `cbox.Items.AddRange(new ListMachinetyp().machinetype);`

Comment: Thanks Johnny, I always forgot the two parentheses after the ListMachine type and that's why I didn't find the array.